# ConfigurationManager function error

Tags: c#, web-services, app-config, console-application

I coded a C# project, and I configured app.config file as follows:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="smUserName" value= "XXX"/>
   <add key="smPassword" value= "XXX"/>
</appSettings>
```

But then I cannot get the `smUserName` and `smPassword` values from app.config:

```
using System.Configuration;

// more code snipped...

public static string smUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("smUserName").ToString();
public static string smPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("smPassword").ToString();
```

Despite the `using System.Configuration` statement, compiling this code gives the error "The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Try `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smUserName"]` and `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smPassword"]`

Comment: Which error are you getting? a runtime error, or the project does not compile?

Comment: What is the error, it is likely that the error is telling you what the problem is!

Comment: the error is "The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the problem is that the code does not compile, try adding a reference to the `System.Configuration` assembly.

Comment: Thank you for your helping. I added reference and the problem solved. But first i coded, i added using Syste.Configuration but not add why ?

Comment: @brsvdn: adding the using statement and the assembly reference are two quite different things. The assembly reference is not added automatically when you add a using statement (the same namespace could be used in multiple assemblies).

Answer (score 1):

What error is giving to you?

You could also try with this:

```
System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader reader;
public static string smPassword = reader.GetValue("smUserName", typeof(string)).ToString();
```

**EDIT**

IF your error is

> the error is "The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the
>   current context"

as stated in the comment, you need to add the reference to System.Configuration to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code like this in C#

```
public static string smUserName = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["smUserName"];
public static string smPassword = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["smPassword"];
```

And also add a reference to `System.Configuration`

EDIT:

You can also try like follows

```
try
{
    AppSettingsSection appSettings =
        config.AppSettings as AppSettingsSection;
    Console.WriteLine("Section name: {0}",
            appSettings.SectionInformation.SectionName);

    // Get the AppSettings section elements.
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Using AppSettings property.");
    Console.WriteLine("Application settings:");
    // Get the KeyValueConfigurationCollection 
    // from the configuration.
    KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings =
      config.AppSettings.Settings;

    // Display each KeyValueConfigurationElement.
    foreach (KeyValueConfigurationElement keyValueElement in settings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", keyValueElement.Key);
        Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", keyValueElement.Value);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
catch (ConfigurationErrorsException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Using AppSettings property: {0}",
        e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I always use the indexer as well, but shouldn't it be equivalent to Get?

Comment: ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings is obsolete and has been replaced by ConfigurationManager.AppSettings..

Comment: @PaoloTedesco, yes it's equivalent to get method indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Configuration;
// all other using as required.

public partial class Admin_UserControls_GridDisplay : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public static string smUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smUserName"].ToString();
    public static string smPassword= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smPassword"].ToString();
}
```

If the code does not work add reference to the website, hope it is website page where u are trying to access the configuration Manager.